# Powershell: Is it possible to set-alias on a piped command?

Tags: powershell

I would like to set the following alias up in my powershell profile:

```
set-alias mem-users get-process | ? {($_.PM -gt 10000000) -or ($_.VM -gt 10000000)} | sort -property PM
```

But when I try this out and call mem-users I just get the results of get-process.  How would I set this up?  Do I have to write a custom function?  The examples for set-alias show a piped command working with the -passThru parameter but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Might consider `{($_.PM -gt 10MB) -or ($_.VM -gt 10MB)}` for readability, instead of `10000000`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aliases are just that - a name substitute and nothing more.  What you want is a function:

```
function mem-hogs
{
    get-process | ? {($_.PM -gt 10000000) -or ($_.VM -gt 10000000)}
}
```

Comment: hehehe mem-hogs why didn't I think of that!?

Comment: There's a missing brace at the end of the boolean check there

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for the heads-up on the missing brace.